# how to select other column before aggregate of a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select Name,TotalTrans as asd from (select Name, COUNT(name) as
TotalTrans from trans group by Name) as sub1 group by Name, TotalTrans
having TotalTrans = MAX(TotalTrans)
```

i want to get the name and the max value of the total transaction(count) that has been occured on the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `TOP` query here:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 name, COUNT(name) AS TotalTrans
FROM trans
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY COUNT(name) DESC;
```

If there could be more than one name tied for the highest count, then use `TOP 1 WITH TIES` or add another sorting level to `ORDER BY` which breaks the tie.

Comment: what if there are multiple name that have the max value?

Comment: It would return an arbitrary row from those 2, @BijiDabes . But Tim does explain what to do.

Comment: @BijiDabes Please read my full answer, which already addresses your comment.

Comment: @BijiDabes You can use `TOP (1) WITH TIES`